# AInput in java : Reading space separated characters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How to read space separated characters in java? I have tried various ways but without success. I want to Count the number of 'O' minus the number of 'I'.

Here is my code is:

```
package RegExp;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CounterO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c;
        int count = 0;

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

            if (c == 'O')
                count++;
            else if (c == 'I')
                count--;
        }
        sc.close();

        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

// INPUT: A B A O I O I O O I O U I O U I

Comment: Can you clarify your question by posting example of input, expected result and preferably explanation of how you know that this result should be expected?

Comment: Also try to explain problem with your current code. Does it now work as you expected for your input?

Comment: Use `next` instead of `nextLine`.

Comment: if you are taking a single character as input  **T**hen use `nextLine()` otherwise if are taking sentence as input then use `next()` .

Comment: Improved text description